# convert foot pounds of torque on a nut to sideways tons of press

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am putting a tapered splined sprocket on a tapered splined shaft that requires approximately 50 tons of press to seat the sprocket on the shaft. How many foot pounds of torque will it take on the nut to achieve the desired tons of press for the sprocket? The threaded part is approximately 4 inches in diameter. The splined part starts at approximated 4.25 inches and tapers up to approximately 6 inches.

Comment: One day we will all use the SI system.

Comment: How are you planning to convert rotation about the shaft to a perpendicular press force?

Comment: Figuring the torque to be applied to a threaded connection to create a certain axial load is questionable without a detailed understanding of the frictional loads inside the joint and even then there will be a good amount of variation.

Answer (score 1):

The way this is done in industry is to apply 50 tons of force then tighten the nut(s). ie, for high pressure flanges , each stud is hyraulically pulled to a specific load then the nuts are tightened.